# Submit a form using <a> tag

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form with some fields and a button with an link. I want to click this button and make the submit of the form.
The form look like this:

```
 <form id="myForm" action="mypage.jsp">
  .....
 <a class="submit-button" href="#">Submit</a>
 </form>
```

and then my js:

```
  $(".submit-button").click(function(){
        if($(".submit-button").hasClass("disabled") == false){ 
            alert("true");
            $("#myForm").submit(function(ev) { 
                alert("submit");
                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        ....
                    }
                });     
                return false;
            });         
        }   
    });
```

My problem is that when I click the button nothing happens. I can see the "true" alert but not the "submit" one. Does anyone know what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

Put the submit handler outside the button click and call the form submit on click .

and i can see from your posted html form has id `myForm` instead of `supportForm`

```
$(".submit-button").click(function () {
    if ($(".submit-button").hasClass("disabled") == false) {
        alert("true");
        $("#myForm").submit(); // or $("#myForm").trigger("submit");
    }
});
$("#myForm").submit(function (ev) {
    alert("submit");
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {....
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because your form has an id `myForm` but you are trying to submit `supportForm`

Comment: this is by accident. will change it

Comment: @novellino will it work if you remove `#` and `ev`? `$('myForm').submit(function() `

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit the form and set the target action to the iframe...
    If you want to AJAX Posting do after iframe has been loaded...

```
HTML:

<form id="my_form" class="myForm" method="post" action="mypage.jsp" **target="iframe123"**>


 </form>
 **<iframe id="iframe123" style="display:none;">

  </iframe>**
  <a class="submit-button" href="#" onclick="">Submit</a>

 jQuery:

  document.getElementById('my_form').submit(); // to submit form
    $('#iframe123').on('load',function(){ // Ajax Post
            alert('Hello');
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });     
            return false;
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cNfMP/1/)

```
  Hope it Helps....
  Thank U
```